# Как поставить свою цветную иконку на программу написанную на tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как поставить свою цветную иконку на программу? Если нельзя, то каким образом это можно сделать?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538416/5909792). С полным путем:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.iconbitmap(r'c:\Python32\DLLs\py.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

Относительный путь:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.iconbitmap('py.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

---

В [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43587905/5909792) предлагается еще такой вариант:

```
imgicon = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(sp,'myicon.gif'))
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, imgicon)
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное!)

Answer (score 1):

```
window = Tk()
window.iconphoto(False, tkinter.PhotoImage(file='image.png'))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]